# How to translate “that doesn’t count”

Tags: phrase-requests

Is there a nice way to translate “that doesn’t count” to mean something like “that is close but isn’t a valid example”. For example in this phrase:

> I’ve never read a book. Sometimes I read the TV guide, but **that doesn’t count**.

I was thinking maybe something like this:

> Mi neniam legis libron. Mi kelkfoje legas la televidan programlibron, sed tio ne **enkalkuliĝas**.

But I can’t find any definitions that seem to match that sense in PIV or ReVo.

Answer (score 8):

Mi pensas ke la plej kutima maniero por esprimi tion estus "tio ne validas".

Comment: Jes, laŭ PIV la dua signifo de valida estas *2 (vastasence) (pp aserto, argumento ks) Havanta valoron, efikon, ĝustecon en difinitaj cirkonstancoj: valida nur post aldona hipotezo.*, kaj tio bone klarigas ĉi tiun uzadon.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe the words ***neglektinda*** or ***nekonsiderinda*** could do the trick. According to ReVo:

> ***[neglektinda](http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/art/neglek.html#neglek.0inda)*** Relative tiom eta, malgrava, ke ĝi ne meritas prizorgon aŭ enkalkulon
>
> ***[konsiderinda](http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/art/konsid.html#konsid.0inda)*** Kiun indas konsideri, ne preteratenti

*Mi neniam legis libron. Mi kelkfoje legas la televidan programlibron, sed tio **estas neglektinda***.

*Mi neniam legis libron. Mi kelkfoje legas la televidan programlibron, sed tio **estas nekonsiderinda** (aŭ **tio ne estas konsiderinda**)*.

Answer (score 1):

Mi tion dirus jene:

"... (sed) tio ne gravas."